# Align label left of toggle switch

Tags: html, css

I have the following code and currently the label shows on the right side of the toggle switch and I would like to have it on its left. The CSS code is part of a file that ideally should not be modified directly, but expanded. Thanks!

```css
.switch {
  /* Finetune the switch */
  --height: 18px;
  --width: 40px;
  --border: 2px;
  --font-size: 1em;
  --switch-color-checked: #1795fe;
  --switch-color-unchecked: gray;
  --dot-color-checked: white;
  --dot-color-unchecked: white;
  font-size: var(--size);
}

.switch label {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-left: calc(var(--width) + 1em);
  min-width: var(--width);
  min-height: var(--height);
  /* Switch Background */
  /* Dot */
}

.switch label::before,
.switch label::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: 0.25s ease-in-out;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.switch label::before {
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: var(--switch-color-unchecked);
  width: var(--width);
  height: var(--height);
  border-radius: calc(var(--height) * 0.5);
}

.switch label::after {
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: var(--dot-color-unchecked);
  height: calc(var(--height) - (var(--border) * 2));
  width: calc(var(--height) - (var(--border) * 2));
  transform: translate(var(--border), var(--border));
  border-radius: calc(var(--height) / 2);
}

.switch input {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  display: none;
}

.switch input:checked+label::before {
  transition: 0.5s;
  background-color: var(--switch-color-checked);
}

.switch input:checked+label::after {
  transform: translate(calc(var(--width) - 100% - var(--border)), var(--border));
  background-color: var(--dot-color-checked);
}
```

```html
<div class="switch">
  <input id="switch__input" type="checkbox">
  <label for="switch__input">
    I am a label that wants to be on the left
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: From what library is the CSS?

Comment: @0stone0 now that you pointed this out I agree that 'library' is not the right word here. It's from a file in the codebase that can't be directly modified since it's used in many places. Unless there is no other way I guess... I have updated the description

Comment: Can we assume that you are not able to modify the markup? You haven't said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See CSS overrides in the HTML panel.

```css
.switch {
  /* Finetune the switch */
  --height: 18px;
  --width: 40px;
  --border: 2px;
  --font-size: 1em;
  --switch-color-checked: #1795fe;
  --switch-color-unchecked: gray;
  --dot-color-checked: white;
  --dot-color-unchecked: white;
  font-size: var(--size);
}

.switch label {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-left: calc(var(--width) + 1em);
  min-width: var(--width);
  min-height: var(--height);
  /* Switch Background */
  /* Dot */
}

.switch label::before,
.switch label::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: 0.25s ease-in-out;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.switch label::before {
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: var(--switch-color-unchecked);
  width: var(--width);
  height: var(--height);
  border-radius: calc(var(--height) * 0.5);
}

.switch label::after {
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: var(--dot-color-unchecked);
  height: calc(var(--height) - (var(--border) * 2));
  width: calc(var(--height) - (var(--border) * 2));
  transform: translate(var(--border), var(--border));
  border-radius: calc(var(--height) / 2);
}

.switch input {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  display: none;
}

.switch input:checked+label::before {
  transition: 0.5s;
  background-color: var(--switch-color-checked);
}

.switch input:checked+label::after {
  transform: translate(calc(var(--width) - 100% - var(--border)), var(--border));
  background-color: var(--dot-color-checked);
}
```

```html
<style>
  /* overrides to be included in your custom stylesheet */
  
  .switch.align-left label {
    display: flex;
    padding-left: 0;
  }
  
  .switch.align-left label::before,
  .switch.align-left label::after {
    position: relative;
    order: 2; /* could technically be 1, but this is more intuitive */
    margin-left: 8px;
  }
  
  .switch.align-left label::after {
    margin-left: -40px;
  }
</style>

<div class="switch align-left">
  <input id="switch__input" type="checkbox">
  <label for="switch__input">
    I am a label that wants to be on the left
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, but any chance this can be achieved with an additional class? The thing is the css is compiled into one big css file that is used everywhere. So even if I add this on top, it's still going to modify all the toggles everywhere to have the labels on the left.

Comment: Of course, though you haven't answered my question above about whether you can change the markup. If not, you'd need to find a containing element to target.

Comment: html can be changed of course, the css as well as long as there are no global side effects.

Comment: Not "of course". How would we know? :) Sure, add a class. I was going to suggest that but didn't know if it was an option.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.switch {
  /* Finetune the switch */
  --height: 18px;
  --width: 40px;
  --border: 2px;
  --font-size: 1em;
  --switch-color-checked: #1795fe;
  --switch-color-unchecked: gray;
  --dot-color-checked: white;
  --dot-color-unchecked: white;
  font-size: var(--size);
}

.switch label {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  gap: 0.5rem;
}

.switch label span {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  min-width: var(--width);
  min-height: var(--height);
  /* Switch Background */
  /* Dot */
}

.switch label span::before,
.switch label span::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  content: "";
  transition: 0.25s ease-in-out;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.switch label span::before {
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: var(--switch-color-unchecked);
  width: var(--width);
  height: var(--height);
  border-radius: calc(var(--height) * 0.5);
}

.switch label span::after {
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: var(--dot-color-unchecked);
  height: calc(var(--height) - (var(--border) * 2));
  width: calc(var(--height) - (var(--border) * 2));
  transform: translate(var(--border), var(--border));
  border-radius: calc(var(--height) / 2);
}

.switch input {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  display: none;
}

.switch input:checked+label span::before {
  background: #f00;
  transition: 0.5s;
  background-color: var(--switch-color-checked);
}

.switch input:checked+label span::after {
  transform: translate(calc(var(--width) - 100% - var(--border)), var(--border));
  background-color: var(--dot-color-checked);
}
```

```html
<div class="switch">
  <input id="switch__input" type="checkbox">
  <label for="switch__input">
  I am a label that wants to be on the left<span></span>
  </label>
</div>
```

I added an extra span to the label and made it look like a radio button. To view the source, refer the [Codepen](https://codepen.io/emaildk/pen/ZEXNeVK?editors=1100).

Comment: I added some comments in the codepen. The `CSS` in the snippet will be completely different since it is compiled from the source `SCSS`.

Comment: Your answer needs to not depend on off-site resources. Comments should be _here_ as well.

Comment: Yup, I wish the Snippet supported `SCSS`.